# Internet explorer ignore @media screen

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, internet-explorer, joomla3.0

i am working on responsive design for web page. I am loading some data with ajax to render forms. I can't find reason, why only internet explorer browser after rendering think, that width is lower than 768px(so it use my responsive template). It must run on ie9 and upper. Any idea, why only ie ignores @media or can be there another problem, why it doesn't work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){   
#topmenu-responsive{
width: 80%;
}
}
```

i try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,9,10,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Completely Work Fine. Check this url Diffrent Diffrent `Browser` . i also check it.

**See Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/xvar89g7/)

**Snippet Example**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){   
#topmenu-responsive{
width: 80%;
background:red;
border:1px solid black;
}
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,9,10,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>  
<div id="topmenu-responsive">
topmenu-responsive Div
</div>
```

**Internet Explore 11**

[image]

**FirFox**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that was only examle. I can't show all of my code, because i am implementing it for company. There is 3k line responsive css and so much code... I have no idea how to describe it better, but any idea, what can be wrong when only on ie it doesn't work? Thanks